# convergence of a sequence to a set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $p>0$ and assume that if $a_n\not\in[-p,p]$, then $|a_{n+1}|-|a_n|<0$. Is it true that $a_n$ converges to $[-p,p]$? If yes how can I prove it? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by convergence of a sequence to a set? Do you mean "is it true that $a_n$ converges to a limit contained in $[-p,p]$"? If so, then that's false. Consider $a_n = p + 1 + 1/n$.

Comment: Moreover, $a_n$ need not converge at all. Consider $a_n = (-1)^n (p + 1 + 1/n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that by "converges to $[-p,p]$ you mean that the limit lies in the set.

Then this is not the case. Take $p = 1$ and the sequence defined by $x_n = 2 + \frac{1}{n}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$. Then whenever $x_n \not\in [-1,1]$, which is the case for every $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$, we have $\vert x_{n+1} \vert < \vert x_n\vert$. However, the sequence converges to $2$, which is not in $[-1,1]$.